# Jupyter on CentOS permission denied

Tags: centos, python

I have an access to a server with CentOS 6.8 via ssh and I want to run my python projects in Jupyter there without distributing global python.

What I tried is install Jupyter under virtualenv and it gives me `Permission denied` when installing terminado. I have a root access and so I forced it to `pip install jupyter`. Yet when I launch Jupyter without root in or out of virtualenv I get `ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_core.command'`. I can launch Jupyter with root but that is not a very good idea.

I also tried to do it with a relocatable virtualenv and this didn't work.

Can I somehow run Jupyter in this circumstances without root access?

EDIT:
A bit of details

Current problem is that when I run `jupyter notebook` without root I get:
`ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_core.command'`

I installed jupyter under virtualenv with pip (pip install jupyter) which without root gives me

```
Collecting terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32" (from notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading terminado-0.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/terminado.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/terminado.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/terminado.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/terminado.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/terminado.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/terminado.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
   error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/Grammar3.5.0.final.0.pickle'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sol3g9mh/terminado/
```

((this worked with root))

I also tried to do the same but on my own PC, where I didn't use root access but user `virtualenv` with `--relocatable` option.

Comment: Which commands have you been using and which exact errors messages did you get?

Comment: @Wieland Added some details. Please feel free to ask anything else about the process.